# How to save multiple files in loop using pylab

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

```
for i in range (0,1):
 for k in range (0,2):
   data = np.loadtxt('data_'+str('%05d'%k)+'/dmp_'+str('%05d'%i)+'.dat')

   for j in range (0,5):
     u[j] += (data[j][2])

   ncount += 1

 for j in range (0,5):
  u[j] /= ncount
  np.savetxt('data/dmp_'+str('%d'%i)+'.dat', (u), delimiter='\t',newline=os.linesep)
```

In this program, I am saving a file in i loop. This works well for one value of i. But I want to save many files in i loop. I am not able to make increments in i loop.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would want to use both loop variables, `i` **and** `j` in your filename, possibly something like

```
np.savetxt('data/dmp_{}_{}.dat'.format(i,j), (u), delimiter='\t',newline=os.linesep)
```

Comment: If I change the value of i then I am getting wrong result. So, I need to do the above mentioned procedure for one value of i and then increase the value. Although I have tried it for both loop variables also and unfortunately it is not working.